# Ionic facebook login how to differentiate new user

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am working on simple ionic 4 facebook login. And save the data in firebase. But i am facing one problem which is whenever i click on login in firestore user data is changing which is obvious. because i am not differentating the user is new or existing. Can any one please tell how can i check if user is available in firebase authentication ?

Here is my code

```
 FacebookLogin(){

     this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
      .then((response: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
      this.onLoginSuccess(response);
      console.log('Logged into Facebook!', response);
      })

      .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));


 }


   onLoginSuccess(res: FacebookLoginResponse) {
    const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
    this.fireAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);

        this.fb.api('me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,picture.width(720).height(720).as(picture_large)', []).then(profile => {
        this.userData = {email: profile['email'], first_name: profile['first_name'], picture: profile['picture_large']['data']['url'], username: profile['name']}
        console.log(this.userData);
        console.log(this.fireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid);

          let userData =  {
          email: this.userData.email,
          username: this.userData.username,
          photo: this.userData.picture,
          phone: '',
          point : '',
          uID: this.fireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid
        };

        this.angularFirestore.collection('AppUsers').doc(this.fireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid).set(userData); // Here is the data saving in firestore
        this.router.navigate(["/select"]);
      })

  });
  }
```

Can any one tell me how can i check user is new or existing ? so if user is existing i dont save them in database.

Comment: You mean the login key in firebase is inserting again as new login key , or the login key inner data are being changed for another user on same key?

Comment: @MostafaHarb i am saving data in firestore. But every time when user login its changing the data. I just want to save one time and if user login again with same facebook login it will not change the data. So i am searching for any way to check user is old or new.

Comment: Okay. You are saving the user as his key right? Then all you need to do is to make a query to search firestore for this key or key.id . If it exists then update or do nothing, else insert the user. Is that what you want?

Comment: hmm yes.........

Comment: https://javebratt.com/searchbar-firebase/

Comment: In this turtorial you can find the way. In filterList method you'll find it.

Comment: filterList(evt) { this.initializeItems(); const searchTerm = evt.srcElement.value; if (searchTerm) { return; //or you can update}else{//inser the data of new user 
}}